# Does it make sense to say "My family is vegetarian" or "My family are vegetarians"?

Tags: word-usage

> [vegetarian](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vegetarian_2): a person who does not eat meat or fish

We can say

> *I am a doctor*
>
> *I am a vegetarian*
>
> [family](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/family_1?q=family) [countable + singular or plural verb]: a group consisting
>   of one or two parents and their children
>
> *All my family enjoy skiing.*

In the above definition, "**family**" is a countable noun & can be followed by a singular or plural verb

But then "**family**" also has other meaning

> [family](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/family_1?q=family) [countable + singular or plural verb, uncountable]: a group
>   consisting of one or two parents, their children and close relations

In the above definition, "**family**" can be a countable noun (an be followed by a singular or plural verb) or an uncountable noun

**Can we say:**

*My family is vegetarian.*

or

*My family are vegetarians.*

Comment: Do the answers to this question: [Family do or does?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15322/2818) answer yours?

Comment: @Laure No, it won't be able to. This is 'cuz the verb *DO* does not takes adjectives. The OP's question is about whether to use the noun *vegetarian* or the adjective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can use the adjective *vegetarian*:

- I am vegetarian.
- My family is vegetarian.

Or you can use the noun *vegetarian*:

- I am a vegetarian.
- My family are vegetarians.

In both cases the noun *family* is grammatically singular and countable.

However, in terms of meaning, in the second example we think of a *family* as a group of individuals. This is why it takes the plural verb *are*.

Comment: I would add that using plural verbs for collections is more common in UK English than American English.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Agreed. "My family are vegetarians" hurts my American ears.  If I wanted to use the noun, I would probably say "Everyone in my family is a vegetarian" or otherwise rewrite to avoid a plural verb with a singular noun.

Comment: I'll third that. "My family are..." is basically *always wrong* to American English speakers. The simplest transformation to make it work would be "My *family members* are..."

Comment: @R..  "My family are vegetarians" sounds perfectly reasonable to me, not at all wrong. I suspect it's regional.